# Python POST request gives <Response [422]> no matter what I try

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I think I have tried just about everything but it always gives me this result:

`<Response [422]>`

I am trying to make a simple python script to get me onto the `blitztactics.com` leaderboard,

Here is the code:

```py
import requests

getURL = "https://blitztactics.com/infinity/puzzles.json"
postURL = "https://blitztactics.com/infinity/puzzles"
puzzleCount = 0
puzzleSolved = 0


while puzzleCount < 2: 
    puzzleCount += 1
    session='my-token-here' 
    tenPuzzles = requests.get(getURL, cookies={'_blitz-tactics_session':session}).json()
    for i in tenPuzzles['puzzles']:
        postReq = requests.post(postURL,cookies={'_blitz-tactics_session':session}, json={"puzzle":{"puzzle_id":i['id'],"difficulty":"easy"}})
        # cookies['_blitz-tactics_session'] = postReq.json()['_blitz-tactics_session']
        print(postReq)
```

Keep in mind the `GET` request works. Also when I do a simple

```
import requests

print(requests.post('https://blitztactics.com/infinity/puzzles'))
```

I get the same error, and when I do

```
import requests

print(requests.post('https://blitztactics.com/infinity/puzzles').json())
```

I get this exception:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Programming/blitztactics/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(requests.post('https://blitztactics.com/infinity/puzzles').json())
  File "/Users/User/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks :)

Comment: The fact that you're getting a JSONDecodeError isn't particularly relevant; that's because the return value with the `422` response is an HTML page that says, "The change you want was rejected. Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to." (which obviously isn't valid JSON).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you try the following

```py
import requests
r = requests.post('https://blitztactics.com/infinity/puzzles')
print(r.text)
```

It returns a HTML page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The change you wanted was rejected (422)</title>
.
.
.
<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/422.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <div>
      <h1>The change you wanted was rejected.</h1>
      <p>Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.</p>
    </div>
    <p>If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

> The change you wanted was rejected (422)
>
> Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.

This message means you cannot POST any data to modify anything on this webpage through this URL.

Comment: 1: When I solve a puzzle(trigger the request) on the website it works and the that is the url in the request, it gives a 200 status code. If you want to reproduce this issue go to this url: https://blitztactics.com/infinity solve a puzzle on easy mode(you have to do it in order to see the request in the network panel) and look and the request in dev tools, you will see it works. If you can't solve a puzzle go to the network panel and open the request called puzzles.json then click response and in the lines of the first object you will see a square, and where it wants you to move the piece on

Comment: 2: on that square. then skip the next move(it is the move your opponent makes) and do the third one.